# How are these two statements equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm having trouble understanding that if a matrix $A$ is invertible, then it's the same thing as saying the equation $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution. Any answers are much appreciated.

Comment: What does it mean to say that $A$ is invertible?

Comment: $A$ is invertible if there exists a matrix $B$ such that $AB=I$.

Comment: It follows that $BA=I$. Now multiply on the left by $B$ in $Ax=0$.

Comment: So, $BAx=B\times0$. Then $BAx=O$. Since $A$ or $B$ cannot be the zero matrix, then $x=0$. Oh okay, thanks GitGud.

Comment: Not quite correct. It's true that $BAx=0$. Thus $Ix=0$, but $Ix=x$, so $x=0$. And this just proves that $$A\text{ invertible}\implies Ax=0\text{ has only the solution }x=0.$$ But the wording in problem implies that there is an equivalence at stake and the other direction is still missing. **Edit:** Still with respect to your mistake, it is possible for $BAx=0$ to be true with $A$ and $B$ both being different from the null matrix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are these statements equivalent?(invertible matrix theorem)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395952/are-these-statements-equivalentinvertible-matrix-theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose this was not the case. In other words, suppose there was some nontrivial solution $\vec{x}_0$ to the equation $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$. Also, $A$ is invertible, so there exists some matrix $B$ such that $AB = BA = I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.  We have 
$$A\vec{x}_0=\vec{0} \implies BA\vec{x}_0=\vec{0} \implies I\vec{x}_0 = \vec{0} \implies \vec{x}_0 = \vec{0} \,,$$
a contradiction.  Now, let us prove the other direction. Assume that the only solution to the equation $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ is trivial and that $A$ is $n \times n$. This means that the columns of $A$ are linearly independent since it is equivalent to the equation $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i\vec{a}_i=\vec{0}$$
having only the solution $x_1=x_2=\,...=x_n=0$ (the definition of a set of vectors being linearly independent), where $\vec{x} = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ and $\vec{a}_1,\vec{a}_2,...,\vec{a}_n$ are the columns of $A$. So, all the columns of $A$ must be pivot columns because there are no free variables by the previous sentence. Since $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, it follows that each row of $A$ must be a pivot row.  These two statements together are equivalent to the fact that $A$ is row equivalent to the $n \times n$ identity matrix $I$.  Hence, $A$ is invertible. $\,\,\square$